# Is there any way to allow a message to appear more than three times before General::stop shuts it off?

Tags: message-coding

I have some Mathematica code that analyzes data in a database and uses `Message` to report when expected data is missing. By default, Mathematica will allow this message to appear only three times before it gets shut off, but I'd like this message to appear as often as the errors do.

The solutions I can think of are

```
Off[General::stop];
```

but this kills limits for all error messages, not just this one,

or just to switch to `Print`, which seems inelegant.

Is there some way to allow this one message to appear more than three times, while leaving behavior unchanged for the rest?

Comment: Perhaps `Assert` would be useful for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
resetMessages[symbol_] := 
 With[{mysymbol = symbol}, 
  Unprotect[$MessageList]; $MessageList = 
   DeleteCases[$MessageList, HoldForm[MessageName[mysymbol, _]]]; 
  Protect[$MessageList];]
```

And you will have to call it after each function...

```
Sqrt[a, b, c, d]; Exp[a, b]; resetMessages[Exp]; Sqrt[a, b, c, d]; \
Exp[a, b]; resetMessages[Exp]; Sqrt[a, b, c, d]; Exp[a, b]; \
resetMessages[Exp]; Sqrt[a, b, c, d]; Exp[a, b]; resetMessages[Exp]; \
Sqrt[a, b, c, d]; Exp[a, b]; resetMessages[Exp]; Sqrt[a, b, c, d]; \
Exp[a, b]; resetMessages[Exp]; Sqrt[a, b, c, d]; Exp[a, b]; \
resetMessages[Exp];

Sqrt::argx: Sqrt called with 4 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>

Exp::argx: Exp called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>

Sqrt::argx: Sqrt called with 4 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>

Exp::argx: Exp called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>

Sqrt::argx: Sqrt called with 4 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>

General::stop: Further output of Sqrt::argx will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Exp::argx: Exp called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>

Exp::argx: Exp called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>

Exp::argx: Exp called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>

Exp::argx: Exp called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>

Exp::argx: Exp called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>
```

Comment: I independently arrived at `$MessageList` as well, but I used it a little differently.  See my answer below.  Also, +1.

Answer (score 13):

#### New Method

FJRA pointed out that my original method will fail in certain cases.  Here is what I hope is a more robust approach:

```
Unprotect[Message, $MessageList]

Message[args___] /; ! TrueQ[$msgClear] :=
 Block[{$msgClear = True},
   $MessageList = DeleteCases[$MessageList, HoldForm[Power::infy]];
   Message[args]
 ]
```

Now the specified message will print an infinite number of times:

```
Table[1/0, {7}]
```

You could use `Alternatives` in `DeleteCases` to make multiple messages infinite.

---

#### Old Method

I also came up with tinkering with `$MessageList` as did FJRA, but my application is a little bit different:

```
Unprotect[$MessageList];

$MessagePrePrint =
  ($MessageList = DeleteCases[$MessageList, HoldForm[Power::infy]]; #) &;
```

Comment: This is more elegant, the only problem I see is that `$MessagePrePrint` is only used when the message has arguments like `1`, `2`. If the message is only a string it doesn't call `$MessagePrePrint`. But in general it avoids the "manual" reset, which is cleaner.

Comment: @FJRA I didn't realize that; thank you.  Please see up updated answer and tell me if you can see any specific problems with my new method.

Comment: I think that's the best way to clear the message list, because calling extra functions is not needed.

Comment: I wanted to do this, but finally decided against it: it will break some unit testing tools which rely on `$MessageList` to catch messages.

Comment: @Szabolcs I can imagine that being a problem.  I wish I knew another way.  p.s. thanks for the corrections to my "MaxMessageCount" question.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you use `Check`.  You could combine it with `Reap`/`Sow` or `Throw`/`Catch`.  Here's an example that counts divisions by zero.

```
SeedRandom[1];
list = RandomInteger[{-2, 2}, {100}];
Quiet[results = Reap[Table[Check[1/x, Sow["bad news"]],
  {x, list}]]];
Length[results[[2, 1]]]
```

Of course, since the second argument of `Check` can be anything, you could arrange for it to alert you any number of ways.