# How to silence all messages associated with a built-in symbol?

Tags: programming

The post title's pretty much says it all...

The reminder of this post just describes the little headway I made with this problem, FWIW.

---

One would hope that

```
In[100]:= Quiet[whatever[], Messages[SomeArbitraryBuiltIn]]
```

would do it, but no.  For one thing, `Messages` shows only those messages that have been defined in the current session, and (from the docs):

```
In[1]:= Messages[NDSolve]
Out[1]= {}

Typically, for system commands, messages are only loaded when they are required:

In[2]:= NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t, s], x[0] == 0}, x, {t, 0, 1}];
        Messages[NDSolve]

             NDSolve::dvlen :
              The function x[t,s] does not have the same number of arguments as
              independent variables (1). >>

Out[2]= {HoldPattern[NDSolve::"dvlen"] :> 
          The function `1` does not have the same number of
            arguments as independent variables (`2`).}
```

Besides, even when `Messages` delivers the goods, it does so in a form that is not readily usable by `Quiet`; e.g.:

```
In[109]:= Take[Messages[General], 3]

Out[109]= {HoldPattern[General::appname] :> 
            The name `1` is not valid for the application. A valid name starts with 
            a letter and is followed by letters and digits., 
           HoldPattern[General::argtu] :> 
            `1` called with 1 argument; `2` or `3` arguments are expected., 
           HoldPattern[General::bktmcp] :> 
            Expression "`1`" has no closing "`2`"`4`.}
```

I'm sure that, after a few afternoons of torture, I'd just manage to come up with an incantation that's just *ridiculous enough* to get all those `HoldPattern`'s to cooperate with `Quiet` (which, for additional pain, has attribute `HoldAll`), but I'd appreciate a leg up on that too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way to silence all messages for a particular symbol.  It requires Unprotecting `Message` but this has been done before, [elsewhere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2463/121), without major problems.

```
Unprotect[Message]

Message[MessageName[NDSolve, _], ___] := Null
```

This silences all messages for the given symbol, here `NDSolve`.

Since R.M apparently finds this inconvenient I'll wrap it up with a bow:

```
voice[sym_Symbol, Off] :=
  (Unprotect[Message];
   Message[MessageName[sym, _], ___] := Null;
   Protect[Message];)

voice[sym_Symbol, On] :=
  (Unprotect[Message];
   Message[MessageName[sym, _], ___] = .;
   Protect[Message];)
```

Now you just need `voice[NDSolve, Off]` or `voice[NDSolve, On]` accordingly.

---

Addressing the last point of your question you can do this:

```
heldnames = Join @@ Hold @@@ Take[Messages[General], 3][[All, 1]]
```

> ```
> Hold[General::"appname", General::"argr", General::"argrx"]
> ```

Then use the [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1937/121):

```
heldnames /. _[names__] :>
   Quiet[(*code*), {names}]
```

Or perhaps more cleanly:

```
heldnames = Unevaluated @@@ Take[Messages[General], 3][[All, 1]]

Quiet[(*code*), {##}] & @@ heldnames
```

Comment: Nulling all the messages is not a good idea because you can't easily turn it back `On`.

Comment: @rm sure you can: `Message[MessageName[NDSolve, _], ___] =.`  If that's too long you could easily write a shorthand function.

Comment: Well, it wasn't about inconvenience in writing it (I can wrap it in a nice function myself too), but rather that this keeps no track of messages that were generated. My initial comment was about turning a chosen message back on (which you can't with this, because you don't know what has been generated). However, I realized you can't do it with mine either (at least, not easily), even though you know which messages have been generated.

Answer (score 5):

This is a slight variation of [Mr.Wizard's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11578/129) (made community wiki because I didn't really add much). Unlike his solution, this one only locally silences the call.

```
ClearAll[silent];
SetAttributes[silent,HoldAll];
silent[s_Symbol[t__]]:=Internal`InheritedBlock[{Message},
  Unprotect[Message];
  Message[MessageName[s,_],___]:=Null;
  s[t]]
```

So you get:

```
silent[NDSolve[{x'[t]==x[t,s],x[0]==0},x,{t,0,1}]]
(*
==> NDSolve[{(x^\[Prime])[t]==x[t,s],x[0]==0},x,{t,0,1}]
*)
```

However, the silence doesn't persist:

```
NDSolve[{(x^\[Prime])[t]==x[t,s],x[0]==0},x,{t,0,1}]
(*
NDSolve::dvlen: The function x[t,s] does not have the same number of
    arguments as independent variables (1). >>
==> NDSolve[{(x^\[Prime])[t]==x[t,s],x[0]==0},x,{t,0,1}]
*)
```

And of course, it doesn't silence unrelated messages:

```
NDSolve[{x'[t]==x[t,s],x[0]==0/0},x,{t,0,1}]//silent
(*
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered. >>
==> NDSolve[{(x^\[Prime])[t]==x[t,s],x[0]==Indeterminate},x,{t,0,1}]
*)
```