# How to limit number of user-defined messages issued per evaluation

Tags: message-coding

I have written code such that if it runs into a particular function, a warning message is issued.  However, it is common for the program to call this function several times in a single evaluation, but the warning message need be issued only once.

How do you limit the number of times a message is issued per evaluation?

Here is an example:

```
 Clear[badness];
 ClearAll[badness];
 badness::oops = "Watch out!  Result could be misinterpreted.";
 badness[0] := CompoundExpression[Message[badness::oops]; 0]

 Clear[reduction]
 f[0] = 0;
 reduction = {f[x_] :> x + f[x - 1] + badness[0]};
```

So, If the user runs the following:

```
 f[5] //. reduction
```

we get:

[image: output of badness]

Is there a way to limit the number of times (without also getting the `General::stop`) the message `badness:oops` is given to the user?  (In the particular case for my code, I would like to limit it to just one time.)

Comment: Good question...I would have expected that `CurrentValue[$FrontEndSession, {MessageOptions, "MaxMessageCount"}] = 1;` or `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, {MessageOptions -> {"MaxMessageCount" -> 1}}]` would the job , but it doesn't -- you still get 3 messages before `General::stop` kicks in :( -- Version 9.0.1.0 Windows 8 64bit).

Comment: Closely related: [(2459)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2459)

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262732/280) answer contains a modern implementation.

Answer (score 4):

It's been a day and no has posted a truly elegant, natural, and general solution, so I'll post a narrow one.

By default, a message is stopped when it occurs three times in `$MessageList`.  One can reduce the number of times a message is printed by pre-loading `$MessageList` with it.

```
Block[{$MessageList},
 Unprotect[$MessageList];
 $MessageList = {HoldForm[badness::oops], HoldForm[badness::oops]};
 f[5] //. reduction
 ]
```

> badness::oops: Watch out!  Result could be misinterpreted.
>
> General::stop: Further output of badness::oops will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

```
(* 15 *)
```

To have it happen automatically every time, use `$Pre`:

```
SetAttributes[foo, HoldAll];
foo[new_] := Block[{$MessageList},
  Unprotect[$MessageList];
  $MessageList = {HoldForm[badness::oops], HoldForm[badness::oops]}; 
  new]
$Pre = foo;
```

Or one could put the code in a function:

```
ClearAll[almostOff];
SetAttributes[almostOff, HoldAll];
almostOff[code_, msgs__] := Block[{$MessageList},
  Unprotect[$MessageList]; $MessageList = List @@ HoldForm /@ Hold[msgs, msgs];
  code
  ]

almostOff[f[5] //. reduction, badness::oops]
```

Comment: Warning: messing with $MessageList might break unit testing tools that can test messages.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method using [`Off`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Off.html) and [`On`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/On.html) triggered by the first appearance of the message.

- I avoid unprotecting any System Symbols by using [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TagSetDelayed.html).
- I use [`$Post`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$Post.html) to turn the message back on.
- Modification of your function is not required; this operates via the low-level `Message` system.

Code:

```
badness::oops = "Watch out!  Result could be misinterpreted.";

badness /: p : MessagePacket[badness, "oops", _BoxData] /; msgLimit =!= True :=
 Block[{msgLimit = True}, Off[badness::oops]; p]

$Post = (On[badness::oops]; #) &;
```

Now:

```
badness[0] := (Message[badness::oops]; 0)

f[5] //. {f[0] :> 0, f[x_] :> x + f[x - 1] + badness[0]}
```

> badness::oops: Watch out!  Result could be misinterpreted.
>
> ```
> 15
> ```

And again:

```
f[5] //. {f[0] :> 0, f[x_] :> x + f[x - 1] + badness[0]}
```

> badness::oops: Watch out!  Result could be misinterpreted.
>
> ```
> 15
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit ugly, but it seems to do what you want.

```
ClearAll[badness];
badness::oops = "Watch out!  Result could be misinterpreted.";
badness[0] /; badness[] := (Message[badness::oops]; badness[] = False; 0);
badness[_] := 0

Clear[reduction]
f[0] = 0;
badness[] = True;
reduction = {f[x_] :> x + f[x - 1] + badness[0]};
```

All it does it keep track of whether it has shown the message or not.  If `badness[]` is `True` it shows the message and sets `badness[] = False`.  This could easily be adapted to keep a count.  The major drawback is that you have to manually set `badness[] = True` to show the message again.