# Is "MaxMessageCount" broken or is its function counter-intuitive?

Tags: front-end, options, customization, undocumented, message-coding

Behavior remains unchanged through *Mathematica* version 13.0.0

---

As [noted by kguler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58074/how-to-limit-number-of-user-defined-messages-issued-per-evaluation/58261#comment166371_58074) the FrontEnd option: `MessageOptions -> "MaxMessageCount"` does not appear to have any effect on the number of times a `Message` is repeated before `General::stop` is issued and that particular `Message` is suppressed.

I would like to know if it is supposed to have this effect but is broken, or if it does something else entirely.  I cannot find any documentation for this Option, and I cannot find any examples of its use either here or in the MathGroup archives.

Comment: No difference in 11.1 for either a smaller or larger value / via kernel messages or console messages.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`On[General::stop]` and `Off[General::stop]` work without the FrontEnd, and the latter shouldn't be necessary for this functionality. Hence it is very doubtful that the developers would attach an option controlling their behavior to the `$FrontEnd`. If such an option exists, it should live in the Kernel.

According to the Documentation page for [`General::stop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/General/stop.html) (emphasis is mine):

> - This message is generated after the indicated message has been generated for the **third** time in a single evaluation.

On the Documentation page for [`Message`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Message.html) we read (emphasis is mine):

> - Between any two successive input lines, the Wolfram Language prints a message with a particular name at most **three** times. On the last occurrence, it prints the message `General::stop`.
> - `Off[General::stop]` makes the Wolfram Language not stop repeating messages.

Hence it looks like the maximum number of printed messages is hard-coded, and isn't supposed to be altered by a user.

Nevertheless, we are able to change the default behavior by overloading `Message`. For example, here is a simple solution intended for [implementing manual subkernel management](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5017071/590388) from my [old MathGroup post](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Mar/msg00139.html):

> I have found the solution. It exploits elegant hack by Todd Gayley.
> Here it is (of course, it must be evaluated in the slave kernel):
>
> ```
> $globalMessageList = {};
> Unprotect[Message];
> Message[args___] :=
>  Block[{$inMsg = True, $MessageList = $globalMessageList},
>     Message[args];
>     $globalMessageList = $MessageList;
>     ] /; ! TrueQ[$inMsg];
> Protect[Message];
> ```
>
> One can fully emulate standard behavior of Messages in the slave
> kernel by checking the current value of `$Line` and comparing it with
> previous value:
>
> ```
> If[TrueQ[$Line > lastLine], 
>   LinkWrite[$kern,  
>     Unevaluated[ExpressionPacket[$globalMessageList = {};]]]; 
>   LinkRead[$kern]]; lastLine = $Line;
> ```

[This recent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262718/280) contains a modern implementation for the built-in `Parallel*` functionality.

For the [Main Loop](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GlobalAspectsOfWolframSystemSessions.html#13888), it can be implemented in a similar manner with the only addition that some built-in functions may [depend](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2459/is-there-any-way-to-allow-a-message-to-appear-more-than-three-times-before-gener#comment255806_2463) on implementation details of `Message`, which updates some internal event counters including `$MessageList` (and affects event listeners as well). Hence it seems reasonable that we have to evaluate `Quiet[Message[mn, args]]` when we don't want a message to be printed, in order do not break this functionality:

```
Off[General::stop];
Unprotect[Message];
Message[mn_MessageName, args___] := Block[{$inMsg = True},
   If[Not[AssociationQ[$EvaluationMessages]] || $EvaluationMessages["$Line"] =!= $Line, 
       $EvaluationMessages = <|"$Line" -> $Line|>];
   If[! NumericQ[$EvaluationMessagesLimit], $EvaluationMessagesLimit = 3];
   If[KeyExistsQ[$EvaluationMessages, HoldForm@mn], 
     ++$EvaluationMessages[HoldForm@mn], $EvaluationMessages[HoldForm@mn] = 1];
   If[$EvaluationMessages[HoldForm@mn] <= $EvaluationMessagesLimit, 
     Message[mn, args], Quiet[Message[mn, args]]]
   ] /; ! TrueQ[$inMsg]
Protect[Message];
```

Here is how it can be used:

```
$EvaluationMessagesLimit = 1;
Do[1/0, 20]
$EvaluationMessages
```

[image: screenshot]

(The screenshot is from version 13.0.0; I don't know from where comes the `ToExpression::sntx` `Message` call.)

Comment: I guess it's still unclear whether `"MaxMessageCount"` is supposed to do this or not? -- Related: [`EvaluationData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationData.html) and ``Internal`AddHandler`` (see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20371/4999)

Comment: @MichaelE2  `On[General::stop]` and `Off[General::stop]` work without the FrontEnd, and the latter shouldn't be necessary for this functionality. Hence it is very doubtful that the developers would attach an option controlling their behavior to the `$FrontEnd`. (Thanks for the links, BTW!)